# Splitting a piecewise signal into different parts

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to analyze and apply filter to a signal (measurements). The problem is while recording the measurements, between 2 timestamps, the value was not recorded, so the program used to record these measurements just connected these 2 loose ends, this is a problem for my algorithm. I want to split the signal into multiple parts based on this abnormality. I need to do this automatically.

Below is an illustration of such an abnormality:

[image: Abnormality of the signal]

Below I have a pic of `plot(diff(t))`:

[image: Plot of diff of t]

I'd like some help with detecting this abnormality and cutting the signal at the point. So in my example the signal will be cut into 3 parts.

Ps - there are 2 abnormalities in my 1st pic, I have just zoomed into 1 to show it properly

Here's the code I came up with so far:

```
a = diff(t);
[value, ind] = findpeaks(a,'thresold',0.5);
for i = 1:length(ind)
  T(i) = %not sure how to use here
end
```

edit with peak picture:

[1st peak of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f56B4.png)

Value of ind : [3557;7550]

Comment: what is the criterion to decide a part can be separate?

Comment: a thresold of diff(t) can be chosen, for this signal lets say 0.7.

Comment: why dont you interpolate the points between it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using findpeaks function?

Below is an example.

```
a=[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0];
findpeaks(a,'threshold',0.5);
```

The result will be below.

[image]

In order to find index,

```
[value, ind]=findpeaks(a,'threshold',0.5);
```

Here, `ind` will be the index of peak.

In your case,

```
a=diff(t);
[value, ind]=findpeaks(a,'threshold',0.5);
firstT=t(1:ind(1)-1);
secondT=t(ind(1):ind(2)-1);
ThirdT=t(ind(2):end);
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome function! But the problem is in this signal i know for sure there are 2 peaks. but I need to automatize this. so i tried writing a loop. a = diff(t);
[value, ind] = findpeaks(a,'thresold',0.5);

for i = 1:length(ind)
T(i) = 
end; not sure how to write the T

Comment: check the edit for better understanding of the code.

Comment: Do you want to cut off variable t?

Comment: Hey I figured that out, I have another problem. ind value is returning with your example [4.5 10]. this is where peak starts. so ideally my 1st signal will be 1:ind(1). but my 2nd signal will be where the 1st peak ends till the 2nd peak starts(ind(2)). How do i find out where does my 1st peak ends

Comment: Yes thats correct, but the problem is ind(1) is the start of the 1st peak which is around 5 in your case. my 2nd signal will start from end of 1st peak till start of 2nd signal. which is ind(1). ind value is returning the points where the peak starts. how do i find where the peak ends. This would really solve my entire problem

Comment: index have to be integer, but your index is 4.5. i can not understand what is your index of peaks.

Comment: I have edited my the main post with a picture of my 1st peak and the value ind is returning.

Comment: so my peak begins at 3556, but the value of ind is 3557. so the peak always ends at ind(1)+1?

Comment: You used diff function. it means when value is greatly changed at the start of next part, there would be peak of differential value. So, the first signal will be until 3356 index. And then, the start of second signal will be 3357.

Comment: So the first is 1:ind(1)-1, second ind(1):ind(2)-1, third ind(2):end

Comment: Hey if you don't mind, i have a problem finding the signal back. For example, i had x as my singal. I found 3 time variables, FirstT, SecondT, ThirdT. How do i get my signal from this 3 time. say x1, x2,x3.